# ajax form link how to call form function with parameters

Tags: forms, ajax, navigation

Is there a good way to use ajax link in form, to call ajax callback function?

I have form elements and i would like to add link, that would call form creation function with some paramaters, so i can change the form accordingly.

The same as form select, which on change submit's form and sends values ...

thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `'#type' => 'link'` form element, and `markup` does not have `#ajax` property. So you are down to buttons and images. You can style them to look like a links. Problem is, button will trigger form validation no matter you want it or no.